# Regex to pull first two fields from a comma separated file

Tags: regex

I want to pull the second string in a commma delimited list where the first value is numeric and the second is alpha.

I'm using `\d[^,]+(?=,)` to pull the numeric value in the first field and just need help with pulling the second value from the "Name" column.

Here's part of a sample file that I'm trying to extract data from:

```
Address Number,Name,Employee Master Exist(Y/N),Auto-Deposit Exists(Y/N),Supplier Master Exists(Y/N),Supplier Master Created,ACH Account Exists(Y/N),ACH Account Created,ACH Same as Auto-deposit(Y/N)
```

//line break here is for clarity and does not exist in file//

```
4398,Presley Elvis Aaron,Y,N,Y,N,Y,N,N
10154,Shepard Alan Barrett,Y,Y,Y,N,Y,N,N
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of a capturing group if you want to match the second string by first matching 1+ digits and a comma.

Then capture in a group matching 1+ chars a-zA-Z and match the trailing comma.

```
^\d+,([a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z]+)*),
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\d+,` Match 1+ digits and a comma (Or use [(\d+),](https://regex101.com/r/BGjcYv/1) if the digits should also be a group)
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[a-zA-Z]+` Match 1+ chars a-zA-Z
  - `(?: [a-zA-Z]+)*` Repeat matching the same as previous preceded by a space
- `)`, Close capturing group and match trailing comma

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FVWzN0/1)

To get a bit broader match you could use this pattern to match at least a single char a-zA-Z

```
\d+,([a-zA-Z ]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]*),
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dJAMcF/1)

---

**Note** that this part in your pattern `\d[^,]+` matches not only digits, but 1 digit followed by 1+ times any char except a comma which would for example also match `4a$ .`

Comment: \K is an "unrecognized escape sequence".  I'm not sure that a capture group is supported either, as the first example doesn't return any values.  For what it's worth, I'm using regular expressions in Laserfiche Workflow.  For the most part, I've had good luck validating regex at regextester.com

Comment: @Mostly_Harmless Can you try it without the `^` anchor like `\d+,([a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z]+)*),` see https://regex101.com/r/AERhl8/1

Comment: that last suggestion, \d+,([a-zA-Z]+(?: [a-zA-Z]+)*), is working.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try this regex:

```
^\d+,([^,]+),
```

This will look for lines:

- starting with one or more digits
- followed by a comma
- capture anything that is not a comma
- followed by a comma

See it at [Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/DSb9e6/2)

If not all lines contain a name, then change the + to a *:

```
^\d+,([^,]*),
```

See [alternative regex](https://regex101.com/r/DSb9e6/3)